# Generating a adjacency matrix representing a DAG

Tags: graphs, adjacency-matrix

Does anyone have a pointer to a resource or, even better, a tip to provide on how to efficiently generate a very large matrix representing a connected graph.

Graph can be randomly created although I would ideally generate a graph of desired size and topology similar to what one can do with [JGraphT](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht).

My general intent is to create a very large graph representation (billions of nodes and edges) in parallel by first generating an adjacency matrix to ensure connectedness and then create a representation (RDF, etc) in parallel.

Any further suggestions or alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: I m sorry but something not clear. do you mean that you want to efficiently verify connectivity of a very large graph ? Or you are looking for efficient ways to store and process a very large graph ?

Comment: Hi AJed, I am looking for both :-) but addressing even one at the time would be helpful.

Comment: have a look at I/O efficient graph algorithms.

Comment: You should first find out if you'll be dealing with dense or sparse graphs. This information is very helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an easy way to generate a random DAG. If a graph is a DAG it can be separated into levels or ranks. The idea is to rank the nodes and randomly generate edges from lower ranked nodes to higher ranked nodes. A little bit of Googling finds the exact same question asked on [stackoverflow a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790337/generating-a-random-dag) (with sample code!).

My only concern is that an adjacency matrix representation for a graph with billions of nodes/edges won't fit in memory. However, it's possible I misunderstood your intent in that part of the question.